# show data base on the current week

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

my tablix is like :

```
w1  |w2  |w3  |w4
----+----+----+---
1   |2   |4   |2
```

if  i'am executing the report in the third week of the month , i need to show data only the  three first weeks

```
w1  |w2  |w3  |w4
----+----+----+---
1   |2   |4   |-
```

is there any way to show only the data before the current week ?

thank you in advance.

Comment: It is little complex, you need to use metrix instead of tables to show data with dynamic columns (column groups). The query behind should have a column for storing "W1,W2,W3,W4"

Comment: It depends on what you want to display? Do you want to show the header of the week like in your case W4 and then the data as "-" or do not show the header/column at all?

Comment: CuriousKid , ineed to show the header W4 , & the the data as "-".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data in the question you can use the below expression to show only data for the week less than or equal to today's date. Remember SSRS weeks starts from Sunday to Saturday. Please replace fields **Fields!Week.Value** with the fields of your weeks(w1,w2,w3...) and **Fields!Value.Value** with the value fields(1,2,4...)

```
=IIF(CInt(RIGHT(Fields!Week.Value,1)) <= DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,TODAY()) - DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,CDate(Format(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-01"))) + 1,  Fields!Value.Value, "-")
```

Comment: But i need to make it for all my columns?however i need a more global solution?

Comment: You can put this expression in all the columns and it will work. If you have lots of column then i would suggest you to create matrix in the report and put this expression in only one cell.